# Browser Content Security Policy Issue in paypal SDK integration

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating the paypal payment system in python Django environment. Now, as per the basic guidelines, the payment is created as follows,

```
payment = Payment({
  "intent": "sale",

  # Set payment method
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },

  # Set redirect URLs
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/process",
    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
  },

  # Set transaction object
  "transactions": [{
    "amount": {
      "total": "10.00",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "description": "payment description"
  }]
})

 

if payment.create():
  for link in payment.links:
    if link.method == "REDIRECT":
      redirect_url = (link.href)
      return redirect_url
    return False
else:
   print(payment.error)
   return False
```

Now, it generates a redirect url properly. But after going into the url (payment page) I am getting a list of errors in both Google chrome and in Mozilla Firefox. Now the error is related to CSP but that is not in my hand cause the rules are mentioned in the paypal page itself. Is there any way out ? Am I mistaking some settings or code ?

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Mozilla Firefox]

Comment: Does the page finish loading? Are you complaining about errors that don't interfere with functionality?

Comment: No the page is not loading. It is showing a paypal error page every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser

In any case, you are using an obsolete integration at both the backend (discontinued v1/payments server SDK) level, and at the front end (full page redirect)

Here is the v2 server SDK you should use: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK , you'll need two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

For modern web design, it is best paired with an "in context" UI that keeps your site loaded in the background, here is a sample: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server